# git push heroku master rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to push my new rails app to Heroku, but it doesn't work. I tried many things, such as:

1. Delete the Gemfile.lock and create another one
2. Run bundle install and bundle install --without production
3. Reinstall the gems 'pg' and 'rails_12factor'

That's what appears in the command line when I type git push heroku master:

```
    Counting objects: 87, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
Writing objects: 100% (87/87), 18.46 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 87 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.2
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.4
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.4
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.4
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.6.2
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.4
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.4
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.4
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.4
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.4.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.4
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.19
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.2
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.4
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.4
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.4
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.6.2
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.4
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.4
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.4
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.4
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.4.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.4
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.19
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to salty-oasis-5413.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/salty-oasis-5413.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/salty-oasis-5413.git'
```

I saw in some tutorials that the first time you execute this command, heroku asks you for a password, but in my case it didn't.

My gem file

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
gem 'rails_12factor', '~>0.0.3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'byebug',  '~>6.0.2'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring',   '~>1.4.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.5.1'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'

end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~>0.0.3'
end
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views


  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: this looks serious:
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_0e499d4b3416be94496280d6a0cdf1f8/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sqllite is not installed for the installation to complete. 
So install sqllite3 as one of your dependency and install it

Comment: I installed the sqlite3 gem. I have that package installed in my pc

Comment: heroku is someone server and by the above command you are pushing your code to someone else server. The heroku server must also have also sqllite installed. so add sqlite3 in the dependency management file of ruby.

Comment: Add sqlite-devel to your gem file as mentioned in this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#declare-app-dependencies

Comment: I added sqlite3, seems that worked when I ran bundle install. Then I tried to upload it to heroku, but nothing seems to work. After bundle install --without production I typed git add . git commit -am "some text" and then git push heroku master

Comment: As far as I know, you cant use sqlite with heroku, you have to use pg. So you should not add sqlite to your gem file.

Comment: Please post your gemfile

Comment: I posted my gemfile. What do you think?